# Why is my ref not working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react 16.3.0-alpha.1 and I am trying to create a ref to check to see if my component is mounted to avoid a 'Can only update a mounted or mounting component' warning.  I am checking the ref in my componentDidMount function but it never has any value for the ref thus it never gets into the if statement.  Does anyone know who to get a ref to work react native?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.productCard = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(handleLoadProduct(this.props.product.id)).then((data) => {
        if (data.response && data.response.images) {
            let images = data.response.images.map(img => {
                return 'https://b2b.martinsmart.com/productimages/' + img.original;
            });

            if (this.productCard) {
                this.setState({imgArray: images});    
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And the view:

```
<View
  ref={(pc) => this.productCard = pc}
  style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#D6D6D6'}}
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `ref` to check if a component is still mounted before using `setState`, you could use a regular instance variable.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  mounted = true;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(handleLoadProduct(this.props.product.id)).then(data => {
      if (!this.mounted) {
        return;
      }

      if (data.response && data.response.images) {
        let images = data.response.images.map(img => {
          return "https://b2b.martinsmart.com/productimages/" + img.original;
        });

        this.setState({ imgArray: images });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }

  // ...
}
```